# cannot swap objects in an array in C++

Tags: c++, swap

i am new to C++ and stuck in the swap stuff
 the code below is a program of sort employee names in alphbetical order and print out the orginal one and sorted one ,but the
 swap method doesn't work
 the two output of printEmployees is excatly the same, can anyone help me? thx

```
    #include <iostream>

    #include <string>

    #include <iomanip>

    #include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


class employee
{

   /* Employee class to contain employee data
   */

   private:
     string surname;
     double hourlyRate;
     int empNumber; 
   public:
      employee() {
         hourlyRate = -1;
         empNumber = -1;
         surname = "";
      }
      employee(const employee &other) :
         surname(other.surname),
         hourlyRate(other.hourlyRate),
         empNumber(other.empNumber){}

      void setEmployee(const string &name, double rate,int num);
      string getSurname() const;
      void printEmployee() const;
     employee& operator = (const employee &other)
    {employee temp(other);
     return *this;}};    

     void employee::setEmployee(const string &name, double rate, int num) {   
      surname = name;
      hourlyRate = rate;
      empNumber = num;
      }
     string employee::getSurname() const { return surname; }  
     void employee::printEmployee() const {
         cout << fixed;
         cout << setw(20) << surname << setw(4) << empNumber << "  " << hourlyRate << "\n";
      }

  void printEmployees(employee employees[], int number)
   {
   int i;
    for (i=0; i<number; i++) { employees[i].printEmployee();   }
   cout << "\n";
   }


void swap(employee employees[], int a, int b)
{
  employee temp(employees[a]);
employees[a] = employees[b];
employees[b] = temp;

}


void sortEmployees(employee employees[], int number)
{
   /* use selection sort to order employees, 
      in employee 

name order
   */


    int inner, outer, max;


    for (outer=number-1; outer>0; outer--)
   {
      // run though array number of times
      max = 0;
      for (inner=1; 

inner<=outer; inner++)
      {
         // find alphabeticaly largest surname in section of array
         if (employees

[inner].getSurname() < employees[max].getSurname())
            max = inner;
      }
      if (max != outer)
      {
         // 

swap largest with last element looked at in array
         swap(employees, max, outer);
      }
   }
}


int main()
{
   employee employees[5];

   employees[0].setEmployee("Stone", 35.75, 053);
   employees[1].setEmployee

("Rubble", 12, 163);
   employees[2].setEmployee("Flintstone", 15.75, 97);
   employees[3].setEmployee("Pebble", 10.25, 104);


  employees[4].setEmployee("Rockwall", 22.75, 15);


   printEmployees(employees, 5);

   sortEmployees(employees,5);
   printEmployees(employees, 5);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `assignment operator` doesn't actually do anything. If you delete it, the default `memeberwise assignment` will do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As told by others, fixing your assignment operator will solve the problem.
I see that you tried to implement `operator=` in terms of copy constructor but missed to do a swap. You can try the below approach if you want to avoid code duplication in your copy constructor and assignment operator.

```
employee& operator=(const employee& other)
{
    employee temp(other);
    swap(temp);
    return *this;
}

void swap(employee& other)
{
     std::swap(surname, other.surname);
     std::swap(hourlyRate, other.hourlyRate);
     std::swap(empNumber, other.empNumber);
}
```

Comment: I've seen the copy-and-swap approach before, but doesn't this implementation just move the duplication from `operator=` to the `swap(...)` method?

Comment: If we look at the operator= in isolation, then it would be moving the duplication from one method to the other. But, if we want to have a swap feature for our class, then it's useful .

Answer (score 3):

This code is broken:

```
 employee& operator = (const employee &other)
{employee temp(other);
 return *this;}
```

It should be something like:

```
employee& operator= (const employee &other)
{
   surname = other.surname;
   hourlyRate = other.hourlyRate;
   empNumber = other.empNumber;
   return *this;
}
```

Comment: great, it works thx so much,btw is the operater do the same thing as create a new employee and copy anohter known employee data to it?

Comment: i got it! is this method means to define what operater "=" will do in this class?